Errors occurred when specifying "Content-Type", "application/json" when using Post request
The error shown in the diagram occurred when I used a POST request on the frontend and specified 'Content-Type': 'application/json'.
errors detail1
errors detail2
errors detail3
This is the code I used
function sendQuery() {
            const requestText = document.getElementById('requestText').value;
            const data = {
                query: requestText
            };

            fetch('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/chat/query', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById('responseText').value = data.msg;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }

The backend uses Springboot. I set up a filter to support cross-origin support

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            /**
             * cross-origin support
             */
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*") 
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true)  // allow cookie access
                        .allowedHeaders("token")
                        .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }

}

I tried to configure Nginx with the following:
        location /chat {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                return 204;
            }
            proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000;
        }

The options method was tested in postman and the response was 200 OK

security CSRF - token?
